Why webvideo on website is jittery?
I am using Firefox on OpenSuse Leap 15.6.  The youtube video seems to look okay.  The motion is smooth.  However, the website videos are jittery or the frames move back and forth.  I did the following troubleshooting steps.

I have checked the older version of OpenSuse (15.2) with the latest Firefox.   The plugin is the same as in the newest version of OpenSuse: OpenH264 video codec.  The web videos older OpenSuse are smooth and normal.  No jittering.
In new OpenSuse (15.6) chrome web browser does not load videos including youtube.
Only Web browser for Gnome is working fine.
I have unstalled ffmpeg-4 and installed ffmpeg.  No difference.   Jittering still there on Firefox.

How do I stop jittery web videos?  How to fix it?   What are other steps to look at?
